# How to show that $\sum_{n=M}^N a_n b_n= \sum_{k=M}^{N-1}s_k(b_k-b_{k+1})s_Nb_N-s_{M-1}b_M$

Tags: summation

> Suppose $a_n$ and $b_n$ are finite sequence of real numbers. Let $s_k = \sum_{n=1}^ka_n$ with onvention $s_0= 0$.Then show that
>   $$\sum_{n=M}^N a_n b_n= \sum_{k=M}^{N-1}s_k(b_k-b_{k+1})+s_Nb_N-s_{M-1}b_M.$$

Trial: I know that  $\sum_{n=M}^N a_n b_n= a_Mb_M+\dots+a_Nb_N$. Then stuck to break this so that I get the desired result. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a $+$ missing in the formula. You get, writing $a_n = s_n - s_{n-1}$,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=M}^N a_n b_n &= \sum_{n=M}^N (s_n - s_{n-1})b_n\\
&= \sum_{n=M}^N s_n b_n - \sum_{k=M-1}^{N-1} s_kb_{k+1}\\
&= s_Nb_N + \sum_{n=M}^{N-1} s_nb_n - \sum_{k=M}^{N-1} s_kb_{k+1} - s_{M-1}b_M\\
&= s_Nb_N + \sum_{k=M}^{N-1}s_k(b_k - b_{k+1}) - s_{M-1}b_M.
\end{align}$$